# Probability that 4 boxes are purchased?

Tags: probability, negative-binomial

> The probability that a randomly selected box of a certain type of cereal has a particular prize is 0.2. Suppose you purchase box after box until you obtained two of these prizes. What is the probability that four boxes are purchased?

My approach was to use negative binomial distribution:

Let $X$ be the number of boxes purchased that don't have a prize until you find two prizes.

P(4 boxes purchase) = P(2 boxes w/o a prize)
=$$\binom{x+r-1}{r-1}(p)^r(1-p)^x$$ = $$\binom{2+2-1}{2-1}(0.2)^2(1-0.2)^2$$ = $$\binom 3 1(0.2)^2(0.8)^2$$ = $$.0764$$

I wanted to know if this is correct approach to solving this kind of probability question?

Comment: yes it is asking me.  What is the probability that you purchase four boxes?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't read the title until now.

Comment: That's ok. The wording of the question confuses me but I remember we are working with the binomial/negative binomial distribution topic. So in this case i figured to use negative binomial because, we are trying to see how many boxes will we have to get before we obtain the particular prize, in this case 2 particular prizes

Comment: To be honest, I would just find the probability that there is one prize in the first three boxes (standard binomial probability question, $3\cdot 0.8^2\cdot 0.2$), and multiply that with the probability that the fourth box has a prize. It seems like the simplest solution to me. Of course, what we get in the end is exactly the same expression as you did, so it should be right.

Comment: Wait binomial & neg binomial can they result in the same answer depending on the approach or is it to be expected?

Comment: As long as you use them properly, they do measure almost the same thing, so I'm not surprised that they give the same result. I just never bothered to learn them all when one of them (with small modifications from time to time) works fine for almost all applications.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification! I don't think i can upvote anything, since i don't see an icon. It could be because this is my first time but thanks all in all!

Comment: @user2807804: there is a small typo in the computed value of $\binom{3}{1}(0.2)^2(0.8)^2=0.0768$

Answer (score 2):

I would note that there are three paths to this result

--++
-+-+
+--+

each with a probability of $0.8^2\cdot0.2^2=0.0256$. Thus, the total probability would be $3\cdot0.0256=0.0768$

This is a slightly different approach getting to the same result.